# MFMailComposeViewController html email image not sent

Tags: html, ios, base64, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm trying to send a local image via the `MFMailComposeViewController`

I've decided to set a html body, so I can design the email sent and also display images in the body (to not have my images in attachment).

Images send are extracted from the current view. My code looks like :

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
NSMutableString *emailBody = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

[emailBody appendString:@"<html><body>"];

///////CREATE IMAGE TO SHARE////////
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(viewToSend.frame.size,YES,0.0);
[viewToSend.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
[img drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
UIImage *outputImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

//Convert image to a base64 string
NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(outputImg);
NSString *imageDataString = [imgData base64EncodedString];

[emailBody appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<p><b><img src='data:image/png;base64,%@'></b></p>",imageDataString]];
[emailBody appendString:@"</body></html>"];

[mailer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];

[self presentViewController:mailer animated:YES completion:nil];
```

When the `MFMailComposeViewController` is displayed, the image appears in it. But in the received email, the image is missing.

My base 64 encoding method is taken from the class `NSData + Base64` created by `Matt Gallagher`

What is happening?

Comment: How are you testing? Some e-mail clients / web interfaces don't support base64 images. You'll likely struggle to get good results. Are you able to link to images on a server instead?

Comment: I'm sending me the emails to test them. I open them with on gmail. Loonking to the source code of the page with the web inspector, in the content of my email, I can find the html code as it had been built in the app. However, the image is just `<img></img>`

Comment: As I say, not all e-mail clients are born equal and you will struggle with images embedded in HTML e-mails.